# Find the basis and rank of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have this matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 4 & 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

a) find a basis for the row space of A and
b) the rank of A

a) $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 4 & 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 4 & 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 14 & 4 & 18 \\ 0 & 7 & 2 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 & 2 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2/7 & 9/7 \end{bmatrix}$$

a) basis: $v_1 = (1,3,1,3), v_2 = (0,1, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{9}{7})$
b) rank = 2. Rank is the dimension of the row space of a matrix and the dimension is the number of vectors in the basis of the row space.

Comment: It looks ok to me... is there any question?

Comment: @javi nah just a sanity check

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, note that the basis you have found can be also simplified as follows $$v_1 = (1,3,1,3), \, v_2 = (0,7, 2, 9)$$

or that as an alternative we can also take as a basis for the row space the first and third row of the original matrix

$$v_1 = (-2,1,0,3), \,v_2 = (-1,4, 1, 6)$$