# Find basis of the kernel and range of this transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Say T(v) = Av where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & -6 \end{bmatrix}$$

So I'm trying to find the basis for the kernel of T and the basis for the range(t) (column space).

basis for kernel of T:

$$= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -5 & 4 \\ 0 & 5 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -5 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

so let $x_3 = t, x_2 = \frac{4}{5}t, x_1 = 2t - \frac{8}{5}t = \frac{2}{5}t

so the basis is = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{4}{5} \\ \frac{2}{5} \end{bmatrix}$. Right?

basis of the range(T). *Why do I have to put this in reduced row echelon form btw? Why are the pivot columns linearly independent?*

further reducing:

$$= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{-2}{5} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

so apparently column 1 and column 2 are linearly independent so that means the corresponding columns in A are linearly independent too right?

So basis for range(T) = $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -5 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Haven’t you asked essentially the same questions before? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914450/find-nullspace-of-this-matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913952/find-the-basis-and-rank-of-this-matrix and others.

Comment: Well, I need help with this one!